# Protractor/Webdriver Accessing DOM elements properties

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

I'm writting e2e tests for a Angular/Polymer app (thus using web-components). Is it possible to have access to DOM properties as in : 
`$0.selectedItem`?
I tried using :

```
elem = browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("my-scrollList")');
```

and then calling

```
elem .then(function (el){
    console.log(el.selectedItem);
});
```

But it doesn't work.

However, if I call the property directly from the executeScript command like so it works but it is very tedious :

```
elem = browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("my-scrollList").selectedItem');
```

Is there a way to access DOM properties through WebElements or Protractor API ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With a CSS selector by selecting the `selected` attribute among the `<option>`:

```
$("my-scrollList").$("option[selected]")
```

or :

```
$("my-scrollList option[selected]")
```

Comment: This workaround doesn't work as the scroll list isn't an <option select> dropdown. It is an angular one made of divs in the shadow DOM.

Comment: @JiggyJinjo, you need to specify that in your post. A reproducible example is more than welcome. What about `element(By.xpath("//my-scrollList/div[@name=../@selected]"))` ?.

Comment: Sorry, I will update my post with a screenshot of the html source tomorrow. "selectedItem" is one of the properties I want to be able to use, but there is also for instance the property "baseList" which contains all the items for that scrollList, however, as I said, only a few of them are loaded in the DOM at the same time (to increase performance).

Comment: @JiggyJinjo Don't post a screenshot of HTML. Just edit your question and add the (properly formatted) HTML as text.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to calls to `$` by chained to find element within a parent. Take a look at [Protractor API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$) .
Your code, probably, should look like this one:

```
elem.then(function (el){
    console.log(el.$('selectedItem'));
});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  He's not asking about traversing the DOM or element locators, he's asking about getting properties from those elements

Comment: you mean get attribute? Take a look at http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute

Comment: @Oleksii no, it is one of the properties of this element. You can find the properties of a web element by inspecting an element and going to the properties tab.